# Black failed, see *blacken-error* buffer for details

Tags: python

I run `blacken` to format my py file but get the error

```
 Black failed, see *blacken-error* buffer for details
```

Check all the buffers but only find buffer `**blacken**` rather than `*blacken-error` buffer.

`blacken buffer` as below:

```
import sys

class Redirection(object):
    def __init__(self, in_obj, out_obj):
        self.input = in_obj
        self.output = out_obj
    def read_line(self):
        res = self.input.readline()
        self.output.write(res)
        return res

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not sys.stdin.isatty():
        sys.stdin = Redirection(in_obj=sys.stdin, out_obj=sys.stdout)

    a = input('Enter a string: ')
    b = input('Enter another string: ')
    print ('Entered strings are: ', repr(a), 'and', repr(b))
```

What's the problem it might be?

Comment: Do you really have a space before the `if __name__ ...` line?

Comment: thank you, yes that's the problem. @DavidNehme could you please transmit the comment to answer.